# Modify SUMIFS formula in VBA - Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a very big Excel file with lots of formulas. One of them refers to another file:

```
    =SUMIFS('T:\3Q2018\[TI -Sept 18.xlsm]Base CM1'!$C$5:$C$59;
'T:\3Q2018\[TI -Sept 18.xlsm]Base CM1'!$A$5:$A$59;
$C16;
'T:\3Q2018\[TI -Sept 18.xlsm]Base CM1'!$R$5:$R$59;
"DOLARES")
```

What I want to do is to easily modify the path. I have the same formula in several cells, so if I need to change it I have to go cell by cell.

For example, the previous formula would be changed like this:

```
=SUMIFS('T:\4Q2018\[TI -Dec 18.xlsm]Base CM1'!$C$15:$C$49;
'T:\4Q2018\[TI -Dec 18.xlsm]Base CM1'!$A$15:$A$49;
$C16;
'T:\4Q2018\[TI -Dec 18.xlsm]Base CM1'!$R$15:$R$49;
"DOLARES")
```

I have to change Sept for Dec, 3Q2018 for 4Q2018 and the range.

That's what I want to make simpler. I've tried with VBA and with another formulas, but have no success.

I've thought in writing the path in one cell and get it from there, but I don't now how.

Any help?

Comment: Usually helps to show what you tried - you should be able to use `Replace(yourFormulaHere, oldPath, newPath)`

Comment: I can't replace because the path and the range changes. So when I replace shows an error

Comment: So replace the range too. You're more likely to get useful suggestions if you show exactly what type of update you need to make - include a "before" and "after" sample formula.

Comment: I would simply go for Crtl+H and replace "3Q2018" with "4Q2018" in every cell and same for the Range. That has always worked for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim c as range, f
'loop over selected cells
for each c in selection.cells
    f = c.formula
    f = Replace(f, "-Sept", "-Dec")
    f = Replace(f, "3Q2018", "4Q2018")        
    '...replace ranges
    c.formula = f
next c
```